# iPhone 5c says I am out of storage when I'm not

Tags: iphone

I have 8.1 GB on my 5c and 11.3 GB on iCloud but I can't take a picture because my phone says there's not enough storage. What's going on?

Comment: Storage warning indicates if there isn't any space on your phone for clicking pictures.

Comment: can you add a bit more information? What is the maximum storage on your phone 16, 32, or 64gb? how much memory is being used? Things like that will help us answer your question. You can either add it in a comment or click the edit button on the post with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - there was 1.6 GB free but it would not let me take pictures because the memory was supposedly full.  Restarting the phone did not help.  I just connected the phone to the PC and it synced in iTunes and then it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 8.1 GB **free** space on your iPhone? Because you probably don't have enough free space, and then it just won't snap any pics. If you just freed up space try restarting the app (double tap home button and then swipe the camera app up, then open it again).

And if your phone is full (storage wise) but you have a lot of space on your cloud than the photos haven't been removed from your phone. HOWEVER, if you are using iCloud photo stream (iOS 5+6+7) or iCloud photo library (iOS 8 & 9) do NOT remove the photos but store them somewhere else (on your PC or Mac via lightning-USB cable or on some other cloud), because they will otherwise be removed from iCloud as well.

All this comes from my personal experience and [the Wikipedia article about iCloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICloud)